# Where can I find a replacement chuck for a drill press?

Tags: tool-repair, drill

I have a Delta ShopMaster DP350 Type I drill press in need of a replacement chuck.  The current chuck is rusted and I can't open it. Other than this issue, the machine cleaned up nicely, rust on the table, stand, and column has been removed, and it runs like it did when it was new. I think this machine is worth this minor repair... if I can figure out what I need to purchase.

When I started digging into this, I quickly found there are a few choices when it comes to chucks and I have no idea how to select one. Everything on this machine is stock - no aftermarket upgrades - so it would be a good start if I could find what type of chuck was included from the factory.

How can I figure out what kind of chuck I need?

Comment: While I'm sure you can find a replacement for the chuck (many types, widely available) perhaps it's too early to give up on the one that came with it. What penetrating lubricants have you tried? Tried hitting the key with a mallet (or lump or wood) when engaged? And has it had a soak in rust remover? A combination of these techniques can work to release mechanisms that seem hopelessly rusted together :-)

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Jacob Edmond, part# 1310049 is the part you want.   There are a limited range of tapers so other chucks will fit. If you look at Jacob's link note the replacement chuck fits 25 other models [1310049 Chuck and Key](http://www.ereplacementparts.com/chuck-p-82793.html)

As for the rusted chuck, heat can break the bonds of rust, as does a good hard wack (but the chuck can be damaged if you go nuts). Applying WD40 or penetrating oil can help. Some folks will bake a rusted part (150 degrees F) and soak in oil and repeat.

I suggest googling among the machinist's groups for more radical approaches.  The manual can be found here: [Delta DP350 Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/37326/Delta-Shopmaster-Dp350.html#manual) [image: Parts Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[Ereplacementparts.com](http://www.ereplacementparts.com/delta-dp350-variablespeed-bench-drill-press-parts-c-3275_3279_7680.html)

Looks like part # 1310049